# Haskell's intersperse in D

Tags: algorithm, strings, d

I am learning D. I'm trying to implement [Haskell's intersperse](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersperse) in D.  I want to use ranges. I feel that the intermediate "interspersed" value is wrong. Additionally, I suspect the concatenation character by character is inefficient. What is a more idiomatic way to implement this function, please?

```d
string translateToSwedish(immutable string english) pure 
{
    string interspersed;
    foreach(char c; english)
        interspersed = interspersed ~ c ~ 'f';
    return interspersed;
}

void main()
{
    assert(translateToSwedish("Hello") == "Hfeflflfof");
}
```

My initial thought was to try `std.range.roundRobin` with repeat:

```d
string translateToSwedish(immutable string english) pure 
{
    import std.range;
    return roundRobin("f".repeat(), english);
}
```

This however is wrong for at least two reasons:

1. `roundRobin` is eager and will evaluate the full range even if another range finishes first. Repeat constructs an infinite range, thus my `translateToSwedish` function is also infinite.
2. This code doesn't typecheck:

   > ```
   > main.d(6): Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (roundRobin(repeat("f"), english)) of type Result to string
   > ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suspect the concatenation character by character is inefficient.

Use [`Appender`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#.Appender):

```
string translateToSwedish(immutable string english) pure
{
    import std.array : appender;

    auto ret = appender!string();

    // optional, but might be handy in your case, since you know the correct size
    ret.reserve(english.length * 2);

    foreach (c; english) {
        ret.put(c);
        ret.put('f');
    }

    return ret.data;
}
```

1. You can construct finite range with [`repeat`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#repeat). Just pass a length.
2. You confused string `"f"` with character `'f'`.

Correct function:

```
string translateToSwedish(immutable string english) pure
{
    import std.array : array;
    import std.conv : to;
    import std.range : repeat, roundRobin;

    return roundRobin(english, repeat('f', english.length)).array.to!string;
}
```

Comment: @JeremyWright, sorry for second function. I remember I tested it in [dpaste](http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/)... Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

<s>Its unfortunate that `roundRobin` doesn't work here, as it sounds just right for the task. Some functions (e.g. `std.range.zip`) have a `StoppingStrategy` that allows you to determine whether to stop at the shortest or longest range, and I'm not sure why `roundRobin` doesn't support this</s>.

As @sigod pointed out, the issue with `roundRobin` was just a simple typo (I missed it too!).
It is probably the best option, but I'll leave my alternative anyways:

```
import std.range, std.algorithm;

auto translateToSwedish(immutable string english) pure 
{
    return english.map!(c => only(c, 'f')).joiner;
}

void main()
{
    assert(translateToSwedish("Hello").equal("Hfeflflfof"));
}
```

`map` replaces each character `c` with the sequence `c'f'`.
`joiner` links these pairs of character into a single range.

Note the use of the `auto` return type. Returning a `string` would imply eagerly committing the result within `translateToSwedish`. However, we don't know what the user of `translateToSwedish` will do with the result; if they are just passing it to another range-manipulating-function, they'd much rather we give them a range.

You'll notice many D functions are written like this. You generally want to keep passing around ranges until it is absolutely necessary to evaluate the result.

With that in mind, lets allow `translateToSwedish` to operate on a range as well:

```
import std.traits, std.range, std.algorithm;

auto translateToSwedish(R)(R english) pure if (isSomeString!R)
{
    return english.map!(c => only(c, 'f')).joiner;
}

void main()
{
    assert(translateToSwedish("Hello").equal("Hfeflflfof"));
}
```

Now `translateToSwedish` is well equipped to be used in a lazily evaluated function chain:

```
auto result = "Hello"
    .translateToSwedish
    .translateToGerman
    .translateToPigLatin
    // and so on
```

Comment: The range version is awesome. Thank you. I'm accepting the other answer as it is closest to my question, but this is a great example of the range idiom.